# Bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, map-projections

Linear bounded operator T on $l^2$ is given by :
$T(x_1,x_2,x_3,..) := (x_1,x_1,x_1,x_2,x_2,x_2,x_3,x_3,x_3,..)$.

Prove that $\frac{T^*T}{3}$ and $\frac{TT^*}{3}$ are orthogonal projections.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 
$$
\langle T^*Tx,y\rangle=\langle Tx,Ty\rangle= 3\sum_nx_n\overline{y_n}=\langle 3x,y\rangle.
$$
So $T^*T=3I$. Since $\ker TT^*=\ker T^*$, we have
$$
\overline{\text{ran}\,TT^*}=\ker(TT^*)^\perp=\ker (T^*)^\perp=\overline{\text{ran}\,T}.
$$
So the range of $TT^*/3$ equals the range of $T$. And it is a projection, since 
$$
\left(\frac{TT^*}3\right)^2=\frac{TT^*TT^*}9=\frac{3TT^*}9=\frac{TT^*}3. 
$$
So $TT^*/3$ is the orthogonal projection onto the range of $T$.

Comment: Just write the inner product.

Comment: And for $TT^*$ I should calculate $<T^*x,T^*y>$ ?

Comment: Can you please help with $TT^*$ ? Thanks in advance

Comment: What for? You wanted to show that $TT^*/3$ is an orthogonal projection, and I gave you a proof of that.

Comment: And for showing that $T^*T$ is orthogonal projection is enough to say that $T^*T$ = $3I$?

Comment: $T^*T$ is not an orthogonal projection. It's $T^*T/3$, that is equal to the identity. The identity is an orthogonal projection.

Comment: And because range of range $\frac{TT^*}{3}$ = range of T and it is a projection we know that it is orthogonal projection?

Comment: No, it's because it is selfadjoint.

Answer (score 2):

Directly from the matrices (the transpose conjugate of that of $T$) you get that $$T^*(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(x_1+x_2+x_3,x_4+x_5+x_6,...)$$

Therefore $$\frac{1}{3}T*T(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$$

and

$$\frac{1}{3}TT*(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3},\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3},\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}, \frac{x_4+x_5+x_6}{3},\frac{x_4+x_5+x_6}{3},\frac{x_4+x_5+x_6}{3},...)$$

which projects over the space generated by $(1,1,1,0,...), (0,0,0,1,1,1,0,...),...$